# Java datafile sharing between classes

Tags: java, file, class, share

I'm making a small program that reads from a file (Serialized objectInputStream), which is a registry list where each entry has a boolean variable that is set to true or false.

In this program I have two separate JPanel-classes. One, the A-class, that can change the value of these variables, and the other, the B-class, checks if these variables are true or false.
These two classes are created under a gui-class with main-method.

If I change the variables in the A-class, how can I see the new updated values in B-class?
I tried to do a ObjectInput- output streams in each class. That means that for each change the class wrote it out to a file and read it back in before changing/ reading.
This works, but is it optimal? Is there a better way to do this?

[image: model of program]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the typical use case for the [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and the [Model view controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) patterns.

The `controller` registers a model and its observers.

It receives requests (events) to make changes and delegates them to the `model`. When the model changes it notifies the `observers` that the model has a new state and they should do something to get those changes.

In your case `Main` could be used as a `Controller` and the `Observers` would be your `Panel1` and `Panel2`

What is left is the `Model` for that you'll need to create a new class witch deals only with reading and writing the file. Actually you seem to have this code in A-Class i.e. `Panel1`. This code needs to be moved from it to the new class.

Note that the jdk already offers an [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) interface and an [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) class.

**EDIT**

Simple example in java ([link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97aag7zvwe43jap/ObserverMVC.zip))

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. 
I tried reading a bit about Observer and observable class. Do you know if there are and tutorials/ hands-on-examples or explanations on how to use this?

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan Hi, i made you a basic example, see the link in the edit section. The zip contains an eclipse project. The code has zero comments, sorry for that, but it is very self explaining.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This was a really cool example. I don't know why I haven't been working with the Observer interface before.. The "update"-method, you could put anything in there, right? I will set aside some time soon and really get in to the Observer/ observable stuff. 

Do you know if this method with observers is more effective than call the read/write methods from a separate class, like MalaKa mentions above?

Thanks again for awesome example! =) =)

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan You're welcome! Comparing to MalaKa's suggestion, i would say it's pretty much the same (Class C -> Model, fire event -> notify observers, update -> update), he has just not given it a name and this is what's all about [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) in general: they describe problems witch are often encountered in the process of software delevopment, show a standard way of how to solve them and give the hole stuff a name, Obeserver, MVC, Factory or whatever...

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan In your use case Observer + MVC can't be less suitable! They have the benifit of separating responsibilities through loosely coupling the buisness logic and the view  witch makes both easily extensible and maintainable.

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan `The "update"-method, you could put anything in there, right?` Yes, anything you want/need to do when the state of the model changes i.e. when it notifies its observers.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Class C that holds the information you read. So Class B reads the Data and puts the information to Class C. When Class A changes a value, it would fire an event to inform Class B.

You could use a `HashMap<String, Boolean>` to store the data. The String is the name of the value and the Boolean is the value. Then you can make method like `public void update(String name, boolean newValue)` in Class B. This method would update the Value and then invoke a method at all classes you need to inform about the new value.

Comment: Should he not rather use Observer design pattern?

Comment: Okey, so, if I create a Class C, with a read-method and a write-method (ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream). 
Then in each of the classes A & B, I implement the class C with 
C methodClass= new C();
then call methodClass.readFromFile();
or    methodClass.writeToFile();


Because I couldnt make them static methods, could I?

Comment: You could have Class C as a singleton class. So you don't call the constructor of Class C but a static method (e.g. `getInstance()`) to retrieve an Instance of Class C. Then Class C holds an Instance of itself (also static) and if this is null (start-value), Class C calls its own constructor in `getInstance()`.

Comment: @JSS I don't know if it's better. It would be better if there will be more classes that listen on the event. But for two classes.. I don't know..

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  =)
I didn't manage to create an getInstance, but I sent the class C through class A & B's constructors. And then called the read/ write- methods of C in each of the classes seperately, everytime a change was made. 
I wonder, does this devour more computer-power than the Observer-design-pattern?

Comment: In a large scale implementation (a lot of classes that access Class C), it probably would be better to do it with the observer design pattern. but in this case, I think it woun't make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) Design pattern for this situation or use case.

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
>   called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to
>   implement distributed event handling systems.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your data from the gui. Try using a Model-View-Controller design.
Furthermore you could work with ActionEvents/ActionListeners in class A/B.
Please provide more information on how the data is displayed.

Comment: I'm too slow with answering -.-. See answers of A4L and JSS.